# Android Studio - Java - "Invalid or corrupt jarfile" ...\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, jar

In my Android Studio java app - error upon running the app:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java.exe" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -jar "D:\work\Android Studio\SongTracker\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar"
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile D:\work\Android Studio\SongTracker\app\build\intermediates\compile_and_runtime_not_namespaced_r_class_jar\debug\R.jar

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The problem started after adjusting xml code - working with a `RecyclerView` inside a `NestedScrollView` - originally ran into error about not being able to find a `@mipmap/ic_launcher` file, then morphed into something like this:

```
Unable to delete directory 'D:\work\Android Studio\SongTracker\app\build'
  Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
```

In doing research found one 'fix' to edit the `R.jar` file by running in the `terminal` window:
`unzip R.jar`  and `jar -xf R.jar` which might have escalated the problem.  It seemed to do nothing however the problem continues to escallate into something I cannot solve all related to my `R.jar` file.

**Here are some of the attempts to rectify the situation - NONE of these made any difference:**

1. deleted R.jar and rebuilt
2. ran `taskkill /im java.exe /f`
3. tried `Clean Project` then `Rebuild Project` - both processes completed without any errors
4. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart in Android Studio
5. restarted computer to clear any file locks
6. Tried reverting my xml changes temporarily to isolate the issue
7. Manually deleted the `app/build` directory, then `Cleaned` and `Rebuilt` project
8. Tried killing `adb.exe` (which shows as adb (32bit) in task manager) from task manager - thanks @General Tony for the suggestion!

Here is the `Application` portion of my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SongTracker"
        tools:targetApi="31">
```

I notice a `R.jar` dropdown menu at the top of my AS desktop - not sure if this was always there and I never noticed or if this is a prompt for further action, here is what I am seeing:

[image]

Thank you in advance for any feedback or insight that you can offer.

best

Comment: Try killing adb.exe (which shows as adb (32bit) in task manager) from task manager, some times it works for me!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @General Tony.  I found `adb` and stopped it, re-built my app but no difference, same `Invalid or corrupt jarfile` error.  I tried opening a different app and no problems with that although I noticed the "run" icon when moused over with the problematic app states `Run 'R,jar'` while mousing over the same icon in the functioning app states `Run app`.  So everything points to `R.jar`

Comment: Why are you executing R.jar file? Clean Build and Rebuild android app. If you can't clean build then try killing adb.exe and delete build folder, it should work. I too face this problem after updating android studio

Comment: Your message prompted me to examine and compare a working app, and the "run" button was the indicator - as I just clicked "run configurations" in the `R.jar` drop down menu and - presto problem solved, everything back to 'normal'.  Thanks again for your comments and also, everything cleaned and built without issue with every step of the process.  Thanks and best!

Comment: Once I ran the configuration for the app the `R.jar` drop down was replaced with the regular `app` drop down.  In the end such a simple fix.

Comment: Actually its a simple question you have complicated it. And I misunderstood, that it was same issue as I face. Anyway Remove R.jar from run configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not exactly sure how I got into this but getting out turned out, at least in my case to be very simple.

In the `R.jar` drop down menu I selected the `Run Configurations` option for the app:
[image: Clicked here to solve]

This was the solution, again for me, after running the configurations the `R.jar` drop down was replaced by the `app` drop down.  I am now able to run the app without problem.

Comment: Click edit configuration and Remove R.jar in left panel by selecting it and click on minus sign. It will remove R.jar from list of configuration.